# React to do list

Tags: reactjs

[my to do list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVSmN.png)

Hey , When I try to type inside the box , my keyboard input does not reflex into it, is is a simple React to do list , thanks in advance.
Here is my code :

```
class Cont extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: '',
      items: []
    };
  }

  onChange = (event)=>{
    this.setState=({term:event.target.value});
  }

  onSubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    const newItems = [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
    console.log(newItems)
    this.setState({
      term: '',
      items: newItems
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form className="Cont" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange}/>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        {this.state.items.map(item => <h3>{item}</h3>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Then describe your strategy thus far, code setup + conditions, and the errors/issues. Also state 'obvious' context that you already know, so that people understand what you have tried. See also [1](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign a value to `this.setState` instead of calling the function.  Should be `this.setState({ term: event.target.value });` without the `=`.

Comment: yeaah , Thanks so mush , It is working now